# When do repulsive forces in a gas actually become dominant?

Tags: gas-laws, van-der-waals-behavior

We say that repulsive forces become dominant when **Z>1**

(*i.e. V<sub>observed</sub> > V<sub>theoretical</sub>).*

But when the difference between V<sub>observed</sub> and V<sub>theoretical</sub>  is **less than b**, shouldn't attractive forces still be **dominant** as the effective volume (*i.e. volume in which gas molecules can move freely*) of real gas is less than ideal gas?

**b** is the volume occupied by 1 Mole of gas molecules

Effective volume of real gas =*V<sub>observed</sub> - b*

Comment: You confuse the effect of the non-negligible own gas molecule volume with repulsive forces. The former leads to higher than expected pressure at given V,T even without repulsive forces.

Comment: It's worth emphasizing that there are no repulsive forces between non-ionized gas particles, other than those that keep them from overlapping with each other when they collide (i.e., other than the forces that cause the individual particles to take up space).  Other than that, the net force between gas particles is always attractive.  For the particles to feel a net repulsive force, they'd need to be squeezed together so closely that they would no longer be a gas.

Comment: To elaborate on theorist's comment above, there are both repulsive and attractive forces, the attractive ones have a much longer range than the repulsive ones which occur on 'contact' of the two molecules or atoms. Have a look at the shape of a Lennard-Jones potential.